# Can't submit iOS app to review

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, review

I'm having issues with Facebook review. I'm currently using Unity building an Android and iOS game. Android apk wasn't too hard to upload, but the iOS build is much more.

I can't download the app from App Store because the app isn't reviewed by the Apple Team, and when i try to "use an uploaded build", following instructions here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/creating-ios-simulator-build-for-review/

My build fail. I found some informations, it seems to be an issue caused by Unity, i changed SDK Version to SDK Simulator, and now i don't know what to do.
Can someone find a way to build this simulator version, can I get reviewed by Facebook without any build ? (As long as i already uploaded and Android build)

Comment: I am also facing the same issue-- this is a real problem-- as far as I can tell, the only way I can build for the simulator from unity is if I remove my references to the facebook plugin from the code.  This is no solution as it will be a version without facebook.  The other alternative is to release to the app store with a button that doesn't work until the facebook review process is completed.  Is there any workaround at all for this?

Comment: If you aren't able to build the iOS Sim yet, you should submit the Android version for review first and submit the iOS version later. This way, it will help speed up your app's approval and you won't keep getting rejected. Hope this helps!

Comment: that's what i was about to do, was not sure it would be faster.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also had this issue. Facebook are fairly quick with their reviews so for me, the answer was to send the app to the app store and allow Facebook's Review team to download it from there to review it.